# Border not given but shown around an image against a colored background

Tags: html, css

I am not going to paste the code as I hope that is not so important here.

an image is placed against a colored background (background made colored by background-color property ). surprisingly blue border is shown around the image.

What is the secret? how can i remove the border?

tnx beforehand.

Istiaque Ahmed
Bangladesh

Comment: Honestly, why don't you think that it's important? Look at the answers; people have to guess what's going on at your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, the image is inside an `a` tag?

A border shows up for an image that is a link unless you explicitly remove the border.

You can remove the border with css:

```
img {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the image inside a link (`<a>`)? That tends to put a blue border around the image. You can remove it by setting a `border: 0` on the image (or some class the image is in).